# Mysql query to copy the structure of a table to create another table 

Tags: mysql

Looking for help in creating a Mysql query to copy the structure of an existing table to create another table.

Answer (score 41):

To create a table as in an exact replica of another table:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table_name` LIKE `old_table_name`;
```

Answer (score 19):

If you want to also copy the contents of the table you can do:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table_name` LIKE `old_table_name`;
INSERT INTO `new_table_name` SELECT * FROM `old_table_name`;
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to copy the table structure including its keys, then you should use:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table_name` LIKE `old_table_name`;
```

To copy the whole table

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table_name` SELECT * FROM `old_table_name`;
```

It will create the table and insert all the data from the old table but without bringing the keys from the old table. So you will need to set the keys for the new table.

Answer (score 4):

Its old thread but if someone needed. If you want create query that will create exactly copy of existing table.

```
show create table <existing table name>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it just saved me so much time!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL query to copy the structure of a table to create another table structure without data another way is...

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name_new` select * from `table_name_old` limit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

also you can use this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'new_table_name' SELECT * FROM 'pattern_table' where 1=0;
```

Comment: Please try to test this. To start with, your DDL has a syntax error.

Comment: @rajah9, The quotation was incomplete, corrected. tnks.