# create table from existing table1 mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to achieve like below in mysql ?

1. if table is exists than insert data from table1 with where condition
2. if table not exists than create new table with same schema and data
   with given where condition
3. New table will be generated based on some condition of PHP Code.so
   need queries for that.

I have tried like below but its not working.I know there is some way in mysql to achieve this using some good queries.

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEMA.new_accounts if not exists AS ( SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.accounts) WITH NO DATA
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004876/mysql-query-to-copy-the-structure-of-a-table-to-create-another-table

Comment: @RameshMhetre Its not duplicate of that question because on that question i cant see any if condition to create table. I know how to create table like another table but i cant get like how to create table with if condition

Comment: Isn't `CREATE TABLE \`new_accounts\` IF NOT EXISTS LIKE \`accounts\`` what you are looking for, almost exactly like that dupe linked?

Comment: In my database accounts table every time exists but new_accounts will be create with same schema and with some schema based on query like 
if not exists then create table new_accounts as select * from accounts where id>=100 else insert into new_accounts as select * from accounts where id>=100

Answer (score 0):

Below is working for me:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `new_accounts` LIKE `accounts`;
```

for data insert you can run below sql with condition:

```
INSERT INTO `new_accounts` SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE column=1;
```

Hope this solves your problem at some level

Comment: Thanks for reply,Its working for me also but i am looking for combination of both queries into single queries.Is that possible ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I would suggest to check condition in your app code instead of sql. You can check another thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409628/mysql-insert-into-table-if-table-exists-otherwise-create-table